# HTTP Audio Stream Framework?

Tags: ios, http, mpmovieplayercontroller, avfoundation

I'm in process of creating radio app (tabbed application) to play http://sample.com/listen.m3u

I have used AVFoundation - AVAudioPlayer, AVPlayer and MPMoviePlayer frameworks thus far.

Experiencing difficulties with volume slider (MPVolumeView) / unable to see volume slider.

My question here is what is the best recommended framework to achieve below tasks?

Play m3u http stream, with play, pause and volume slider?

Comment: Are you testing on the device or on a simulator? The simulator does not support the usage of a the MPVolumeView (neither routing button nor volume slider).

Answer (score 0):

Use `AudioStreamer` by `mattgallagher` which is `library` for `audio streaming`. According to your requirement, u should use this.

Refer [AudioStreamer](https://github.com/mattgallagher/AudioStreamer) library.